# insert into table values from another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: Person and Item. I just created a new column in the Item table called item_lab_fk.

I need to select the person_lab_fk values from the Person table and place it in the item_lab_fk column in the Item table.

I tried running the following piece of sql query but it's not working properly.

I would be grateful if someone would kindly show me where the error lies in the code below:

```
INSERT INTO item (`item_lab_fk`)
  SELECT person.person_lab_fk
  FROM person WHERE person.per_oid = item.item_created_by
```

Note that the `item.item_created_by` field is the `person_id` from the Person table.

Comment: Could you provide us with the DDL-statements for the item and person tables? Also, please provide us with the error message since it probably contains hints of what goes wrong.

Comment: Do you get an error message, if so what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hand typed and untested but should put you on the right path

```
UPDATE Item
SET Item.item_lab_fk = Person.person_lab_fk
FROM Item INNER JOIN Person ON Person.per_old = Item.item_created_by
```

Comment: Many thanks for all the suggestions provided :)
Below is the solution which worked for me.

I made some small modifications to John Petrak's solution because i was getting some error message

Comment: UPDATE item, person
SET item.item_lab_fk = person.person_lab_fk
WHERE person.per_oid = item.item_created_by